# React SyntaxHighlighter only on <pre> block

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using `react-quill` to write a blog which will contain code blocks (which react-quill supports). I'm saving my blog as a JSON string in my database (mongodb) which I then retrieve on the front end.

I'm currently using `react-render-html` to render the string which is fine, however I want to throw the code blocks (only the code blocks) into `react-syntax-highlighter`. I'm searched the documentation of react-syntax-highlight and react-render to see if there's a way I can do this but I'm struggling to find a solution.

At present I can either render the entire thing in a code block (including the content that is not code)

```
<SyntaxHighlighter language="javascript" style={docco} children={
 blog.body
} />
```

Or I can render the entire thing as html, without syntax highlighting.

```
{renderHTML(blog.body)}
```

Is there a way I can selectively apply syntax highlighting to just the  tags of the rendered JSON string? Or a better way I could take this?

Any help appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So you basically want to selectively apply syntax highlighting only to the `pre` tags.

There is now way to do it unless somehow we can programmatically detect these pre tags and then wrap them in some other React component that can render them with syntax highlighting.

My recommendation is to do some kind of pre-processing of the text before rendering it, detecting the pre tags and then replacing them with one of the react components discussed here from the [list of code highlighting libraries](https://www.frontendeng.dev/blog/2-best-code-highlighting-libraries-for-react#highlight).